# Do you know alternatives in Ant to generate project documentation?

Tags: ant, documentation-generation, apache-forrest

I'm wondering are there more current and active alternative tools to the [Apache Forrest](http://forrest.apache.org/index.html) product for project documentation that developers are using?. It seems to be stuck in v0.8 release since 2007.

I'm thinking about using the `maven site` via Ant to generate a HTML report with the various javadoc, pmd and findbug reports for my project. Just wondering what other developers are using out there.

Answer (score 1):

maven can grenerate copious amounts of project documentation.

I'd point you to the maven documentation for this, but the maven documentation is, ironically, rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

We generate most of our documentation *from source* using a new open source build system for Java called [EBuild](http://ebuild-project.org/) ([features](http://ebuild-project.org/Discover.html)) that is a great alternative to Maven.  You may have to adopt EBuild-specific conventions to make the most of that though.

There's some detailed articles on the [deficiencies of Ant](http://ebuild-project.org/articles/a_critical_retrospective_ant.html) and also [Maven](http://ebuild-project.org/articles/maven_the_bad_parts.html) on the site.